# What do the loyalty and happiness boosters do?

Tags: spore

I understand that they boost happiness and loyalty, but I have absolutely no idea how. When using it I don't see any change with the happiness of the colonies, whether they were happy or unhappy beforehand. Also, I didn't even know there was such thing as loyalty before I saw this item. I don't think it can be loyalty to other empires, because I'm pretty sure you can't place building on other empires planets.

Answer (score 2):

Well taken from SPORE wiki

[The Happiness Booster](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Happiness_Booster) keeps colonists happy and can prevent an uprising

[As for Loyalty Booster.](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Loyalty_Booster) This tool prevents colony planets with unhappy cities from striking, allowing you to max out a planet's spice-mining efficiency.

So in conclusion both high Happiness and Loyalty doesn't let your colonies to start [riot and uprising](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Uprising) and helps with production of spice.

Answer (score 1):

An additional bonus of the Loyalty Booster (not sure if this is also applicable to Happiness Booster), is that many attacking aliens will target it. Since it has an impressive 10,000 health, it can be useful for drawing fire away from your precious cities.